# Comparing arrays in Go language

Tags: arrays, go

How can I correctly compare two arrays in Go?

For instance, how can I compare two dimensional arrays with *int* entries, or any other types?

How deep is that comparison?

Comment: Just to clarify, since people often make this mistake - do you mean slices or arrays? There's a difference in Go. If you're not sure what you mean, could you paste some example code of creating one of these things and we'll figure it out.

Comment: @joshlf13 arrays not slices.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To compare two arrays use the [comparison operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) `==` or `!=`. Quoting from the link:

> Array values are comparable if values of the array element type are comparable. Two array values are equal if their corresponding elements are equal.

As a 2D (or ND) array fits the above requirement, you can compare it in the same way.

The question *"How deep is that comparison?"* doesn't make sense for arrays.

Comment: @Tom: Where do you see any slices? They're never mentioned in the question nor in this answer.

Comment: @jnml that's true. It's just that a lot of people get confused because in Go []int{1,2,3} is a slice but [3]int{1,2,3} is an array.

Answer (score 31):

For "Deep" comparison, you can use [`reflect.DeepEqual`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual).

> DeepEqual tests for deep equality. It uses normal == equality where possible but will scan elements of arrays, slices, maps, and fields of structs. In maps, keys are compared with == but elements use deep equality. DeepEqual correctly handles recursive types. Functions are equal only if they are both nil. An empty slice is not equal to a nil slice.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    a := []byte{}    // empty slice
    b := []byte(nil) // nil slice
    fmt.Printf("%t\n%t", bytes.Equal(a, b), reflect.DeepEqual(a, b))
}
```

Returns:

> true
>   false

The caveat is that it's slow.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/J6FGlEeZPl)

Comment: There's additional caveat that both arrays have to have exact same ordering.

Comment: @MaciejSzulik That's not a caveat, that's a requirement. Lists aren't supposed to behave like sets.

Answer (score 10):

If you have 2 `int` slices/arrays try this:

```
func IntArrayEquals(a []int, b []int) bool {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return false
    }
    for i, v := range a {
        if v != b[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

**NOTE:** this is for 1D arrays, but you can rewrite it for 2D.

Comment: @angry_gopher bytes.Equal()

Comment: I am surprised you don't mention the input conditions here: both slices MUST be sorted for the solution to work. But I guess here equality means contents AND order.