# how to compare two arrays is same with any orders value in golang

Tags: arrays, go

I'm still new in golang. I want to know how I check if two arrays are considered equal if those arrays contain the same values in any order. I have read answers in this [Comparing arrays in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561219/comparing-arrays-in-go-language) and I know if I use `==` the arrays are considered equal if those arrays contain the same value in the same order.

for example, I want these arrays considered equal.

```
a := [3]int{1,2,3}
b := [3]int{3,2,1}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Go 1.18 or later, you can use `sort.Ints` to sort the arrays before comparison, and then `slices.Equal` to compared the sorted slices.  Something like:

```
func EqualIgnoringOrder(a, b []int) bool {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return false
    }

    sort.Ints(a)
    sort.Ints(b)

    return slices.Equal(a, b)
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"

    "golang.org/x/exp/slices"
)

func EqualIgnoringOrder(a, b []int) bool {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return false
    }

    sort.Ints(a)
    sort.Ints(b)

    return slices.Equal(a, b)
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3}
    b := []int{3, 2, 1}

    if EqualIgnoringOrder(a, b) {
        fmt.Println("arrays are equal")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("arrays are not equal")
    }
}
```

Notice that here I'm using slices rather than arrays; to quote https://go.dev/blog/slices, "Arrays are not often seen in Go programs because the size of an array is part of its type, which limits its expressive power."

We can't use `==` to compare slices, which is why we use `slices.Equal` (which is only available for go 1.18 or later).